# How to extract all substrings between certain characters by using regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have hundreds of lines to parse. They are like:

```
key1 = $global.path
key2 = prefix +$global.name
key3 = prefix + $default
key4 = prefix+$lib.id + $value + $args.id + ' some between ' + $global.title
```

where `$global` represents a certain dict in Python called `'settings'`. I would like to replace all terms '$global.key' with dict value `settings['key']`. `$lib` and `$args` are similar to `$global`.

If there is only `$default` without a '.', should be same as `$global.default`

And all `'+', ' + ', '+ ', ' +'` should be removed directly.

How to do this in Python? I can do it in plain Python. But I think it is better to use regular expressions. All should be case insensitive.

First recognize which dictionary to look for. Get the key. Then get the value in the dictionary. Finally replace the placeholder with the value.

For example, `settings['name']` is '`carl`'. Then the line:

```
key2 = prefix + $global.name
```

should be changed to:

```
key2 = prefixcarl
```

Thanks. Any help is appreciated:)

=============================================================

Edit:

What I have got at hand:
1. Dictionaries for $global, $lib, $args
2. Hundreds of lines.

What I want to get:
Same number of lines with the placeholders `$some.some` changed to corresponding values in the dictionaries. And '+' is represented as 'concatenation'.

Comment: @Tomalak, thanks. Check the post updated.

Comment: You've updated the post by restating what you have and what you want. You somehow forgot to post some of your code that shows how much *of your own effort* you've put into solving this.

Comment: @Tomalak. Er, nothing done yet...

Comment: See? That's part of the problem. This site is not supposed to be a place where you can let other people do your homework. The above is not a hard problem to solve. 5 lines of Python code are enough, but apparently you have not even tried. That's a little sad.

Comment: @Tomalak. I said i can do it in plain Python. String matching and replacing is not so complicated indeed. But solving it by regular expression is really out of my reach. So I ask here.

Comment: That's not an excuse for not trying. It's equal to saying *"I can solve it in plain English. Explaining what needs to be done is not so complicated indeed. But solving it using Python is really out of my reach. So I ask here."*

Comment: @Tomalak. I used python for 3 weeks until now. I know little about regular expressions. And my question is too specific to google and find an answer. This site has some similar threads, but cannot solve. I have to learn RE syntax for some time. Then learn Pyhon RE handling. Then until now I do not know what 'lambda' means. I do not know how to reach this concept, which solves my problem. I think this site is supposed to save learning time and learn things more efficiently. So I do not see any problem about asking it here. "English" and "Python" has a far distance between.

Comment: My sentence was completely analogous to yours. I only exchanged two words and the whole statement fell apart. This site is to help you. Not to post tasks we should solve. I appreciate that you're a Python beginner. That's not a problem. On the other hand there are literally thousands of Python/regex examples on the Internet, there is rubular.com to develop regexes interactively. You just decided that it would be quicker to ask here than to actually dig into the topic. And you're right, it is. It's still a little sad. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `re.sub` with a functional "replace" parameter:

```
settings = {}
settings['name'] = 'carl'

key2 = "foo $global.name bar"

import re
print re.sub(r'\$(\w+)\.(\w+)', lambda m: settings[m.group(2)], key2)
```

[If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub)

Here's a version that supports multiple dicts (assuming they are defined globally) and 'default' arguments:

```
 re.sub(r'\$(\w+)(\.(\w+))?', lambda m: globals()[m.group(1)][m.group(3) or 'default'], key2)
```

If your dictionaries are defined in a function, they don't belong to `globals()` anymore, but rather to `locals()` of that function. You have to use a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) to gain access to them:

```
import re

def some_func():
    settings = {'result_dir':'dir'} 
    args = {'run_id':'id'} 

    vars = locals() 

    print re.sub(r'\$(\w+)(\.(\w+))?', lambda m: vars[m.group(1)][m.group(3)], '$settings.result_dir + $args.run_id')

some_func()
```

And finally, if the dicts are in a class, you can use `getattr(self)` to access them:

```
class X(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.settings = {'result_dir':'dir'} 
        self.args = {'run_id':'id'} 

    def some_method(self):
        print re.sub(r'\$(\w+)(\.(\w+))?', lambda m: getattr(self, m.group(1))[m.group(3)], '$settings.result_dir + $args.run_id')


X().some_method()
```

Comment: Thanks. But it uses only one dictionary 'settings', how to make it able to support multiple dicts?

Comment: Hi, I run this:
`settings = {'result_dir':'dir'}
        args = {'run_id':'id'}
        print re.sub(r'\$(\w+)(\.(\w+))?', lambda m: globals()[m.group(1)][m.group(3)], '$settings.result_dir + $args.run_id')` 

I run it on the console, it is correct. But when run in from the python file, it reports "KeyError: 'settings'", what is the problem?

Comment: @Cai: yes, it does! I answered in the post.

Comment: May I further ask how to access the dictionary is this case if I put the dict inside a class? How to use the 'self' variables? Or could you please give some pointers to learn more? Thanks.

Comment: @Cai: I updated the post ;) BTW it might be better to post a new question if you need further explanations.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would mind that next time. You are really a Python expert! Thank you very much.